# Not-pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: geometry, lebesgue-measure

Consider a fundamental parallelotope $F$ for a $n$-dimensional lattice $\Lambda$ and consider a convex, measurable, centrally symmetric subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$, which we call $E$, such that $m(E)>2^nm(F)$, where $m$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Clear that
$$
\mathbb R^{n}=\bigsqcup_{x\in\Lambda}(x+F)
$$
hence
$$
\frac12E=\frac12E\cap\mathbb R^n=\bigsqcup_{x\in\Lambda}\left(\frac12E\;\cap(x+F)\right)
$$
which yelds to
\begin{align*}
m(F)&<\frac1{2^n}m(E)=m(1/2E)\\
&=\sum_{x\in\Lambda}m\left(\frac12E\;\cap(x+F)\right)\\
&=\sum_{x\in\Lambda}m\left[\left(\frac12E-x\right)\cap F\right]
\end{align*}
Then my book says that from the last one, it follows that the sets $\left(\frac12E-x\right)\cap F$ cannot be pairwise disjoint. Why?

It's clear that if
$$
\bigcup_{x\in\Lambda}\left(\frac12E-x\right)=\mathbb R^{n}\;\;\; (*)
$$
supposing by contradiction that the $\left(\frac12E-x\right)\cap F$ be pairwise disjoint then we'd have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x\in\Lambda}m\left[\left(\frac12E-x\right)\cap F\right]
&=m\left(\bigsqcup_{x\in\Lambda}\left(\frac12E-x\right)\cap F\right)\\
&=m\left(F\cap\bigsqcup_{x\in\Lambda}\left(\frac12E-x\right)\right)\\
&=m(F\cap\mathbb R^n)\\
&=m(F)
\end{align*}
and finally $m(F)<m(F)$, absurd!

The problem is I don't know how to prove (*), permitted it's true!

Can someone help me? Thank you all

Comment: Where in what book?

Comment: Daniel Marcus' Number Fields, chapter 5, pages 137-138. It's a lemma by Minkowsky, which helps to improve the constant $\lambda$ defined at the beginning of the chapter.